# Why can't I transfer ssh-keys to os-login?

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

I've been trying to transfer my public ssh-key to my gcloud project but I get the following error:

```
   gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys add --key-file=.ssh/gcloud-key.pub --ttl 365d
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.os-login.ssh-keys.add) FAILED_PRECONDITION: <eye3-stackless title='/FocusBackend.MutateData, APPLICATION_ERROR'/>APPLICATION_ERROR;MutateDataHandler{username=cloud-cluster-proxy, role=focus-backend-proxy, run_as_role=, debug=, fingerprint=0} failed com.google.focus.backend.server.OperationDeniedException: Reason: UNIQUE_VIOLATION; A field in the mutate request violates unique constraint. See the SchemaValidationMessage on the RPC side channel for structured details useful for dynamic client use.  <FailedGaiaId:##########>
Stack trace:
com.google.focus.backend.server.OperationDeniedException: Reason: UNIQUE_VIOLATION; A field in the mutate request violates unique constraint. See the SchemaValidationMessage on the RPC side channel for structured details useful for dynamic client use.  <FailedGaiaId:##########>
        at com.google.focus.backend.server.AbstractHandler.checkSpannerUniqueViolation(AbstractHandler.java:1383)
        at com.google.focus.backend.server.AbstractHandler.checkKansasMutateStatusOk(AbstractHandler.java:1527)
        at com.google.focus.backend.server.MutateDataHelper$32.checkRpcStatusOk(MutateDataHelper.java:9241)
        at com.google.focus.backend.server.MutateDataHelper.onKansasUpdateComplete(MutateDataHelper.java:9479)
        at com.google.focus.backend.server.MutateDataHelper.access$5400(MutateDataHelper.java:341)
        at com.google.focus.backend.server.MutateDataHelper$30.callbackEx(MutateDataHelper.java:8915)
        at com.google.focus.backend.util.HandlerCallbackFactory$RequestHandlerCallback.execute(HandlerCallbackFactory.java:395)
        at com.google.focus.backend.util.HandlerCallbackFactory$BaseHandlerCallback.callback(HandlerCallbackFactory.java:358)
        at com.google.focus.backend.util.HandlerCallback$1.runInContext(HandlerCallback.java:145)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
        at io.grpc.Context.run(Context.java:565)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:166)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
        at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
        at com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.runInContext(ContextRunnable.java:50)
        at com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable$1.run(ContextRunnable.java:39)
        at io.grpc.Context.run(Context.java:565)
        at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:166)
        at com.google.tracing.GenericContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(GenericContextCallback.java:72)
        at com.google.tracing.GenericContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(GenericContextCallback.java:64)
        at com.google.common.context.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:36)
        at com.google.common.labs.concurrent.TimedRunnable$1.call(TimedRunnable.java:37)
        at com.google.common.labs.concurrent.TimedRunnable$1.call(TimedRunnable.java:34)
        at com.google.common.labs.concurrent.TimedCallable.call(TimedCallable.java:52)
        at com.google.common.labs.concurrent.TimedRunnable.run(TimedRunnable.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at com.google.focus.backend.server.MonitoredThreadFactory$MonitoredThread.run(MonitoredThreadFactory.java:89)
;AppErrorCode=13;StartTimeMs=1548155251448;ServerTimeSec=0.16378735;TCP;Deadline=9.905;CliLog=-1;SrvLog=256;FailFast;EndUserCredsRequested;ReqSecLevel=none;RespFormat=UNCOMPRESSED;/FocusBackend.MutateData;LastReqID=902e2568409590b4;LastGlobalID=0;Server=[2002:a0d:2917::]:4428
```

I'm running windows 10 and I've updated my gcloud utils. People with unix systems don't seem to have this problem in our team.
I've tried generating new keys, creating keys in another project and transferring from cloud compute engines accrossa projects but I keep running to the same error.
gcloud compute os-login ssh-keys list gives me zero entries. I've also reauthed etc.

Help would be appreciated.

-Thx for the tips

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the instructions at [1] and make sure 'os-loging' is enabled. If it still fails, try it from another machine for the same account to discard any local issues.

[1]https://medium.com/infrastructure-adventures/centralized-ssh-login-to-google-compute-engine-instances-d00f8654f379

Comment: No luck there even from another machine. I currently have the same account for two different projects. One is for organization and the other one without organization structure. Can this have an effect? I know that most of the people in our organization have this kind of setup and it works.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer your public ssh-key to your gcloud project, you can follow the below procedure:

- Created a new SSH Key:

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/[USER]-key -C [USER]

When it appears the below message, just hit [ENTER] key two times,

Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
   Enter same passphrase again:

- Restrict access to the new SSH Key:
  chmod 600 ~/.ssh/[USER]-key
- Get the contents of ~/.ssh/[USER]-key.pub

cat ~/.ssh/[USER]-key.pub

- In your project add the public SSH keys [1]:

  In the Google Cloud Platform Console, go to the VM instances page.

  Click the name of the instance that you want to modify.

  Click Edit in the toolbar.

  Under SSH Keys, click Show and edit. The section expands to show all of the instance-level public SSH keys.

  Modify the instance-level public SSH keys:

  To add a public SSH key, click Add item. This will produce a text box. Copy the 
  contents of your public SSH key file and paste them in to the text box. Repeat this process for each public SSH key that you want to add.

  To remove a public SSH key, click the removal button next to it:

  Repeat this process for each public SSH key that you want to remove.

  When you are done, click Save at the bottom of the page.
- Connect to your VM instance:

ssh -i ~/.ssh/[USER]-key [USER]@[IP ADDRESS]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only

Comment: I think that because os-login is enabled in the project it overwrites the securites for project level ssh key management done like you described